# webpack css optimization and minify

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I use webpack 4 and need to optimize and minify css after build comand.
I found optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin but this plugin doesn't work.
Do you use these plugins or loaders for optimizing css or not? Do we need to use it or not?

Answer (score 5):

With webpack 4 you need to bring your own. To minify the output, use a plugin like optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin. 
However, note that setting optimization.minimizer overrides the defaults provided by webpack, so make sure to also specify a JS minimizer:

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true // set to true if you want JS source maps
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },
  plugins: [

  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "css-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks